# Alternative to missing() inside a function

Tags: r

I want to detect if a variable is missing inside a function without calling the `missing()` function. I've found two alternatives, but they both seem crude.

## Alternative 1

It seems that a variable that is missing has the environmnent *class* "name" but it seems intuitively wrong to use this construct:

```
a <- function(a, b){
  e <- environment()
  if(class(e[["b"]]) == "name")
    e$b <- a

  print(b)
}
```

## Alternative 2

I guess a possible solution is to use `parse` and `eval` but it seems just as crude as the previous solution:

```
a <- function(a, b){
  e <- environment()
  if(eval(parse(text = sprintf("missing(%s)", "b"))))
    e$b <- a

  print(b)
}
```

## Background

I need this as I'm changing the API and I would like to loop over all the old argument names within the `...` and send a warning that the user should update to the new parameter names. This is why `missing()` doesn't work, my current setup is:

```
# Warnings due to interface changes in 1.0
API_changes <-
  c(rowname = "rnames",
    headings = "header",
    halign = "align.header")
dots <- list(...)
fenv <- environment()
for (i in 1:length(API_changes)){
  old_name <- names(API_changes)[i]
  new_name <- API_changes[i]
  if (old_name %in% names(dots)){
    if (class(fenv[[new_name]]) == "name"){
      fenv[[new_name]] <- dots[[old_name]]
      dots[[old_name]] <- NULL
      warning("Deprecated: '", old_name, "'",
              " argument is now '", new_name ,"'",
              " as of ver. 1.0")
    }else{
      stop("You have set both the old parameter name: '", old_name, "'",
           " and the new parameter name: '", new_name, "'.")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do these have to be in ... ?  What about just doing this: `myfun <- function(rnames = rowname, rowname) { if (!missing(rowname)) .Deprecated("rnames", old = "rowname"); ... }`

Comment: As the function is used in markdown documents, possibly multiple times I would like to keep the old arguments functioning for a while. If for no other reason, I have a ton of documents that I would otherwise have to remake.

Comment: But `rowname` does still work using this code.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck the thing I don't like with the solution is that I have enough arguments in the help and as I understand it I would need to explain all of the old parameters in the Rd-file from CRAN-compatibility. Even with just `#' @param old_arg Deprecated see new_arg`, it doesn't seem that user friendly.

Comment: Just say `deprecated` in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Gosh,-- do we really have to point you to the appropriate `fortune` entry concerning `eval(parse())` ?
Anyway,what's wrong with looping over the contents of `dots<-list(...)` ?  It's not a time-pig by any means.

But my fundamental response is:  you've made a mistake by allowing valid or invalid arguments within the `...` entries.  I don't know why you set up your previous function that way, but it's probably much cleaner, and safer, in the long run to eliminate this construct from your updated release.  There's a reason that functions&packages come with help pages.  Much as I approve of back-compatibility, I don't think you're doing anyone a favor here.  Further,  it's not clear to me how or why you'd want a required argument to be passed via `...` . And if it's not required, then you don't want to emulate `missing` in the first place.

Your users will very quickly :-)  realize that they've got invalid argument names.  Regardless of whether you provide this transitional set of warning messages, they'll either adapt,  or emigrate from your code to other options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to have a softer transition and at the same time avoid having a large number of old parameters in the docs. I have the `...` for other reasons and I figured that I'd use it for during the transition period. As you note, the current solution is no time-pig - I was mostly curious if it `class(e[[n]]) == "name"` was the correct way to identify an environment variable that is an unevaluated parameter.